# Implementing Login Using JSON in Titanium

Tags: json, authentication, titanium-mobile

I hope someone will help me. 
I have an API which is implemented with JSON web-services. I want to implement Login. A user is created and I need to have login the user. That is when I enter username and password it must log the user in .

I have read the [tutsplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-user-authentication/) tutorial, but I am unable to authenticate the user. Can anyone help me out.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
title:'Login',
backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var username = Ti.UI.createTextField({
top:'10%',
borderRadius:3,
hintText:'username',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
width:'80%',
height:'auto',
left:'10%',
right:'10%',
touchEnabled: true, 
});
win1.add(username);
var pass = Ti.UI.createTextField({
top:'30%',
borderRadius:3,
hintText:'password',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
width:'80%',
height:'auto',
left:'10%',
right:'10%',
touchEnabled: true,
passwordMask: true  
});

win1.add(pass);
var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({  
title:'Login',  
top:'50%',  
width:'60%',  
height:'15%',  
borderRadius:1,  
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}  
});  
win1.add(loginBtn);

var url = 'http://qudova.com/api.php?function=AuthenticateUser&u=ns.nadeem.m@gmail.com&p=qudovatest';
var json;
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  
loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)  
{  
if (username.value != '' && pass.value != '')  
{  
    // Here I will get the Token (asdfasdf....)
    loginReq.open("GET",url);  
    authstr = 'Basic ' +Titanium.Utils.base64encode(username.value +':' +pass.value); 
    loginReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authstr);

    loginReq.send();  
}  
else  
{  
    alert("Username/Password are required");  
}  
});
loginReq.onload = function()  
{  
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // Here I have made a check if the Token is returned successfully it will alert the user that he authenticated 
    if (jsonObject.Token == "asdfadsfasdfadsf")  
        {  
            alert("Authenticated");  
        }  
    else  
        {  
            alert("response.message");  
        }  
}; 
win1.open();
```

Thanks in Advance. Is my concept clear ?

Comment: in your code you used 3(!!!) ways to authenticate. 1. Plain Text credentials as GET parameters in URL. 2. Basic Auth Header generated from fields and 3. POST params (plain) also generated from fields. Which one should work / is implemented in backend??? When i copy your url and paste it in the browser i get your expected answer (asdfasdf...) without especially logging in. Please proof your concept and clarify what you really want to do!

Comment: I want to authenticate the user on the Basis of `setRequestHeader` parameters. in this way when authenticated the Token (asdfasdf...) will be returned and I can make a check on token to verify the authentication and alert the user that he is verified. I have edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a JSON array as response. So you should access `jsonObject[0].Token`.

```
// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
title:'Login',
backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var username = Ti.UI.createTextField({
top:'10%',
borderRadius:3,
hintText:'username',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
width:'80%',
height:'auto',
left:'10%',
right:'10%',
touchEnabled: true, 
});
win1.add(username);
var pass = Ti.UI.createTextField({
top:'30%',
borderRadius:3,
hintText:'password',
keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_DEFAULT,
width:'80%',
height:'auto',
left:'10%',
right:'10%',
touchEnabled: true,
passwordMask: true  
});

win1.add(pass);
var loginBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({  
title:'Login',  
top:'50%',  
width:'60%',  
height:'15%',  
borderRadius:1,  
font:{fontFamily:'Arial',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}  
});  
win1.add(loginBtn);

var url = 'http://qudova.com/api.php?function=AuthenticateUser&u=ns.nadeem.m@gmail.com&p=qudovatest';
var json;
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();  
loginBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e)  
{  
if (username.value != '' && pass.value != '')  
{  
    // Here I will get the Token (asdfasdf....)
    loginReq.open("GET",url);  
    authstr = 'Basic ' +Titanium.Utils.base64encode(username.value +':' +pass.value); 
    loginReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authstr);

    loginReq.send();  
}  
else  
{  
    alert("Username/Password are required");  
}  
});
loginReq.onload = function()  
{  
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // Here I have made a check if the Token is returned successfully it will alert the user that he authenticated 
    if (jsonObject[0].Token === "asdfadsfasdfadsf")  
        {  
            alert("Authenticated");  
        }  
    else  
        {  
            alert("response.message");  
        }  
}; 
win1.open();
```

Alternatively you can change your backend implementation, that the result will be an object instead of an array.

Nevertheless you should change your backend because at the moment it's possible to authenticate via plain GET parameters.

Comment: I figured it out before your answer, BTW i will still accept it because this is the right answer . THanks